# Change My Profile using Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to allow a user to change his/her profile attributes like Country,city, email etc. from my application using Azure AD Graph API. Currently using following code

```
IUser CurrentUser = await activeDirectoryClient.Me.ExecuteAsync();
CurrentUser.City = "SomeCity";
await CurrentUser.UpdateAsync();
```

This code throw anexception "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". But i have allowed all API permissions of Azure AD and Graph API as seen in below image
[image]

Startup.Auth.cs Code to authenticate User:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {  
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                     {
                             var code = context.Code;
                             //After token download, Set the token download flag
                             HttpContext.Current.Session["NewTokenDownloadFlag"] = true;  
                             ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

                             string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                             AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));

                             AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                                code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                     }
                }
            });
```

Code to Get Access Token:

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
    {

        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

Note: If assign "User Administration Role" from Directory roles, then this code works and user can update his/her profile, but this role enable him/her to change any other user's profile that i don't wanna allow. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: For changing password i'm using following code and this code is working fine with same permissions.

```
await activeDirectoryClient.Me.ChangePasswordAsync("Old_Pwd", "New_Pwd");
```

Comment: Did you click the `Grant permissions` button?

Comment: How do you authenticate? Are you using delegated or application-only access?

Comment: @JoyWang yes i clicked Grant Permissions button

Comment: @juunas This is a web app and it is using Azure SSO (client credential flow) to authenticate a user.

Comment: @juunas Password changing functionality is working fine with  the same permissions.

Comment: Client credential flow does not authenticate a user, only an app

Comment: @juunas can u guide me here what to do whether on azure portal side or code side, so that user can change its profile attribute using my web app.

Comment: @umer Can you please edit the post to include the code you're using to obtain the access token?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret please review updated post with code to get access token. thanks